# Access triggered subsystem parameters in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, subsystem

I have a simulink block with a triggered subsystem. Inside the subsystem I have a MATLAB System block. I want to modify the parameters of this MATLAB System block programmatically. For this I tryed to access the MATLAB System block using:

```
get_param('toplevelSystem/triggeredSubsystem/MATLAB System','param')
```

but I can't even access the `triggeredSybsystem`. I get the following error

```
Invalid Simulink object name: toplevelSystem/triggeredSubsystem/MATLAB System'

Caused by:
No block called 'triggeredSubsystem' could be found.
```

why Simulink does not find the subsystem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I didn't notice the name of `triggeredSubsystem` had a space at the end... -.-' from the simulink model it's impossible to see that. That a thing that maybe need to be improved in the new releses.

Cheers,

Bruno